# Datadog log parsing

Tags: logging, dashboard, datadog

log a csv file into datadog. I want to group the data by one column  I created a parsing rule yet I am not able to parse the csv Would appreciate any help in referencing my parser-
myParsingRule1 %{data:group_name1:csv("group_name,resident,current_master_residents,missing_residents,extra_residents,process_date")}

@group_name1.group_name when i filtered the logs yet the csv is not being parsed so I cannot create a pie chart grouped by group_name I want to know how many residents did we catch per group how do i reference my parsing rule?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.